# Screen Overlay Detected PopUp Handle Programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm facing a issue on the devices with Marshmallow +  and i'm trying to find out a solution programmatically.  When ever the code executes for asking user a dangerous permission a "screen overlay detected" popUp appears and takes the user to "Draw Over apps" Settings. It's hard for a user to determine which app to select to turn off the overlay feature. A very ordinary user might get confused what to do and could see it as a gimmick, would simply press back button and kill the app. Turn out to be a bad user experience.
It may be not rally necessary to turn off this feature. Is there a way to handle this programmatically. By pass this Popup and stay on the main track?

Comment: Below link did not solve my problem